# Is there a way to get the process ID of a console program I've just started in the background?

Tags: windows, batch-file, background, pid

Suppose I just started the following programs in the background:

```
START /B CMD /C tomcat.exe
START /B CMD /C tomcat.exe
START /B CMD /C tomcat.exe
```

and I want to kill the second one. Because they have the same image name, I can't use `taskkill` to kill them using `tomcat.exe` or I'll kill more than I want.

What I want is to get the process ID of each when they're kicked off.

My question is: **Is there a way to get the process ID of a console program I've just started in the background?**

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28191039/2861476) could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a utility [batch function](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php) that'll let you spawn a process and have its PID set to a variable.  Copypaste this into the bottom of your script, after the final `exit /b` or `goto :EOF` so it can only be executed by `call`.  It looks complicated (and truth be told it is perhaps a little more complicated than the current situation requires), but it ought to handle backslashes and quoted arguments if you should ever need to recycle it for future projects.

```js
:spawn command args
:: sets %PID% on completion
setlocal
set "PID="
set "return="
set "args=%*"
set "args=%args:\=\\%"

for /f "tokens=2 delims==;" %%I in (
    'wmic process call create "%args:"=\"%" ^| find "ProcessId"'
) do set "return=%%I"

endlocal & set "PID=%return: =%"
goto :EOF
```

If you `wmic process call create "ping localhost"` from a console, you'll see how this works.  Unlike `start /b`, using `wmic process call create` to run a new asynchronous process will output the PID of the process as it's started.

Call the function above like this:

```js
call :spawn tomcat.exe
set "instance1=%PID%"

call :spawn tomcat.exe
set "instance2=%PID%"

call :spawn tomcat.exe
set "instance3=%PID%"

:: kill the 2nd one:
taskkill /PID "%instance2%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wmic`](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) to help you get ProcessId:

```
wmic process where "Name='tomcat.exe'" get processid, commandline
```

You have to get Pid of each new tomcat instance to be stored in a file (pid1.txt, pid2.txt, ...) so you can kill the one you want.

You could also take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25622550/4584335